# How does one access a grandparent this in JS?

Tags: javascript, prototype

How could I access a grandparent "this"?

```
function F(){}
F.prototype.foo = 5;
F.prototype.getFoo = function(){ return this.foo; };
F.prototype.container.getFoo = function(){
   /* What goes here to return 5? */
};
```

Comment: So  where does container come from?

Comment: You cannot access this if its not in the immediate scope of the object/instance. You must call `container.getFoo` as so `var x= new Foo();` then `x.container.getFoo.call(x)` to set the scope of getFoo explicitly

Comment: In this example, any `this.foo` is `5` unless you set an instance's `foo` to something else.

Comment: Before coming up with an answer to your question, you should explain where this code comes from, because it looks really bad. For starters, why are you declaring a property (`foo`) on the prototype? Then it looks like you're namespacing (`container`) on a prototype....very very bad.

Comment: It was an example I created to demonstrate the syntactic question I had about accessing properties of a parent object's parent object from within a method called as rootObj.parent.method().

Comment: @user2958725 - oh good. In that case, just don't write code like that and you won't have a problem - it's very poor.

Answer (score 0):

```
function F = function(){}
F.prototype.foo = 5;
F.prototype.getFoo = function(){ return this.foo; };
F.prototype.container = {
  getFoo: function(){
   /* What goes here to return 5? */
  }
};

var f = new F;
f.getFoo(); // 5, as it should be.
f.container.getFoo(); // how do i make this 5?
```

In the above code, `f.container` has no accessible relation to `f`'s prototype - it was not constructed from it, it is merely a namespace hanging off the `F.prototype`

The only thing you can do is either pass in a new scope, or change the scope that it's executed in like this:

```
F.prototype.container = {
  getFoo: function(newscope){
   return newscope.foo;
  }
};
//instantiate f as an instance of F...
f.container.getFoo(f);
```

OR

```
F.prototype.container = {
  getFoo: function(){
   return this.foo;
  }
};
//instantiate f as an instance of F...
f.container.getFoo.apply(f);
```

I advocate that you use neither of these solutions and instead google around for some information on namespacing in JavaScript and prototypical inheritance.